# Using a plot line comparator in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I use Highchart to display an inverted graph with multiple series.

an HighStock chart should be better for what I need but I had to use it with the  `inverted` option that is available only in HightChart.

How can I display a comparator line following my cursor on my multiple series chart ?

( like in [this example](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare) from HighStock )

secondary question :  why is it so many differences between highstock and highcharts ?
would be perfect to use the better of those two worlds together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I've found it.

using the tooltip shared option as:

```
tooltip: {  
    shared: true, 
    crosshairs: true 
}
```

it works great on inverted charts too, the misunderstood was because this setting is enable by default in HighStock graphs.